# In wpgeodirectory, when using WPML how to translate the map

Tags: wordpress

I want the map to appear in a certain langauge when the site is shown in this certain language. Default is English.

Answer (score -1):

Place this to the geodirectory-compatibility.php which is in your theme /inc folder:

```
function gd_wpml_default_map_language( $language ) {
            return defined( 'ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE' ) ? ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE : 'en';   
        }

add_filter( 'geodir_default_map_language', 'gd_wpml_default_map_language' );
```

Comment: if you have answer for your own question then why posting here?

Comment: @Ashikirsha: because that's explicitly encouraged; Stack Overflow is about sharing knowledge, after all. See the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), or [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) by Jeff Atwood, founder of Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is a way to have an index of my findings. Otherwise, how I would remember what I have done. Please, put +1 to my answer. I do not like negative votes.